# Excluding single directory under protected Wordpress site from htpasswd protection

Tags: .htaccess, password-protection, .htpasswd

Despite a good deal of searching here I haven't been able to find the solution to this problem.

I have an .htaccess file that is protecting a Wordpress site that I am developing.  I would like to protect the entire site except for the directory /images/, but I can't work out how to do this.  At the moment my .htaccess file, in the root of the site, looks like this:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

# basic password protection
<IfModule mod_authn_file.c>
 AuthUserFile /home/*****/.htpasswd
 AuthName "Username and password required"
 AuthType Basic
 <Limit GET POST>
  Require valid-user
 </Limit>
</IfModule>
```

Could someone help me to amend this to allow open access to the /images/ directory?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new .htaccess-file in the /images/-directory:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Satisfy any
```

This should remove the password protection for this folder.